# Possible to spy/mock Sql Server User Defined Functions?

Tags: sql, t-sql, unit-testing

Is it possible to mock/spy functions with T-SQL? I couldn't find anything mentioning it. I was thinking of creating my own implementation using the SpyProcedure as a guideline (if no implementation exists). Anyone had any success with this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're going to mark me down the least you could do is give a reason. So I may improve my questions in the future.

Comment: It's not possible to spy UDFs. The main use of spying is to see what procedures a stored procedure is calling, and UDFs are rarely (at least in my experience) that complicated.  Do you have an example of the kind of UDF you're trying to mock?  (I was not the person who marked you down!)

Comment: Thanks John. Basically my situation is that I am unit testing a number of functions, and one function calls another one and so on. At the moment the only thing I can do is just copy the unit test for a function across if it is being called from the current function I am testing. This of course is bad, and so spying a UDF would be ideal for me here.

Comment: Ah, and if you're calling different functions from within the 'outside' functions depending on input, then you might want to spy it to see how it was being executed.  Unfortunately I don't have any suggestions (having not done it) but it could be useful in some cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL Server functions cannot have side-effects. That means, in your test you can replace the inner function with on that returns a fixed result, but there is no way to record the parameters that were past into the function.

There is one exception: If the function returns a string and the string does not have to follow a specific format, you could concatenate the passed-in parameters and then assert later on that the value coming back out contained all the correct values, but that is a very special case and not generally possible.

To fake a function, just drop or rename the original and create your own within the test. I would put this code into a helper function, as it probably will be called from more than one test.

Comment: So if drop/rename a function in the test, the changes will be reverted after the test finishes? Due to how tsqlt tests run?

Comment: That is correct, if you don't "mess" with the transaction that tSQLt opened.

Comment: Couldn't you also do a temp table in the test, access it within the function to record parameters passed in then assert table on it back in the test?

Comment: @JDPeckham: No, SQL Server does not allow any side-effects in functions. That includes temp tables: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/2014